# ListVIew in Fragment Very Laggy

Tags: java, android, listview, android-fragments

I have a ViewPager with 3 fragments. The rightmost fragment has a ListView inside it. The problem is that on two weaker phones I tested this on, it works seemingly smooth and not laggy. However, when I test it on my Note 3, the transition from the middle fragment to this one is very laggy and over 300 frames are skipped according to the logcat. Also, if I lock the phone and then unlock it back onto the ListView it is very laggy to scroll or do anything, unless I swipe left twice to the leftmost fragment. This is my onCreateView, onAttach and onStart methods as well as the adapter below.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_c,container,false);
    mainalyout = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.linear_layout_listview);
    listView =  (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.followed_cities);
    horizontal_scroll = (HorizontalScrollView) view.findViewById(R.id.horizontal_scroll_view);
    swipe = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.scroll_up);
    layout =  (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.scroll_view_layout);
    swipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.swipe_refresh_layout);
    return view;

}
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    context = MyApp.getContext();
    session = new SessionManager(context);
    userString = session.getUserDetails();
    username = userString.get("username");
    viewPager = (ViewPager) activity.findViewById(R.id.pic_pager);
    parent = (FragmentActivityTesting) activity;
    username = userString.get("username");
    queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
    followed_cities = session.getFollowedCities();
    try {
        citysearcher = (citysearcher) activity;
    } catch(Exception e) {}
    try {
        slideshowready = (slideshowready) activity;
    }catch (Exception e) {}


}
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
}
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(this);
    if (followed_cities.contains("")) {
        followed_cities.clear();
    }
    if (getActivity().getIntent().getStringExtra("launcher").equals("add")) {
        get_followed(username);
    }
    if (followed_cities.isEmpty()) {
        followed_cities.add(new CityShort("","NONE"));
        ArrayAdapter<CityShort> adapter = new EmptyAdapter();
        adapterr = adapter;
        listView.setAdapter(adapterr);
    }
    else {
        ArrayAdapter<CityShort> adapter = new MyListAdapter();
        adapterr = adapter;
        listView.setAdapter(adapterr);
    }
```

My adapter :

```
private class MyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<CityShort> {
    public MyListAdapter() {
        super(getActivity(), R.layout.followed_item, followed_cities);

    }
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        itemView = convertView;
        if (itemView == null) {
            itemView = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.followed_item, parent, false);
        }
        TextView city_name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.followed_city_txt);

        final String curr_city = followed_cities.get(position).getCityName();
        city_name.setText(curr_city);
        city_name.setTag(followed_cities.get(position).getCityId());

        if (curr_city.length() > 15) {
            city_name.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 18);
        }
        listView.setOnTouchListener(swipeDetector);

        return itemView;


    }
    @Override

    public int getViewTypeCount() {

        return getCount();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {

        return position;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I saw you had 2 listviews (`findViewById(R.id.followed_cities)` and `findViewById(R.id.horizontal_scroll_view)`). The horizontal listview is not well-implemented for recycling items.

Consider a better official support solution with [RecyclerView](http://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html). It supports both vertical and horizontal and provides better performance (as least the number of frames skipped will be less than current listview).

Comment: Horizontal Scroll View is only loaded once, it isn't repopulated, it simply displays icons to the user.

Comment: The `getView()` method is also having performance problem also. Consider have ViewHolder pattern implemented. @mankee

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html ViewHolder pattern guide.

Answer (score 0):

Two things that I see:

1) You have several LinearLayouts. I'm not certain what your xml layout looks like, but if LinearLayouts are nested they can certainly reduce visual rendering time. RelativeLayouts are more efficient(though I do use LinearLayouts when I'm first writing the xml file, because it's a little less time consuming for me as a general setup, then to later go back and update to using RelativeLayout).

2) You're doing all of these calculations on your MainThread, which is also Android's GPU essentially. You might be interested in processing all of this on a separate thread, this will certainly reduce rendering time. Check out "extends AsyncTask" and "Intent Service".

Comment: Which calculations are you referring to? Don't all view changes have to be done on the main thread since you can't access the UI elements from outside it?

Answer (score 0):

Change these things and try if works..

```
ViewHolder holder = null;
    if (convertView == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.followed_item, parent, false);
       city_name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.followed_city_txt); //Make this class level variable
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Replace your adapter with this

package com.munk.gaanasync;

import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;

import java.util.zip.Inflater;

private class MyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<CityShort>
{
    public MyListAdapter()
    {
        super(getActivity(), R.layout.followed_item, followed_cities);
       mInflater = (LayoutInflater)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        ViewHolder holder = null;
        itemView = convertView;
        if (itemView == null)
        {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            itemView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.followed_item, parent, false);
            holder.city_name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.followed_city_txt);
            itemView.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
        {
            holder = (Viewholder) itemView.getTag();
        }

        final String curr_city = followed_cities.get(position).getCityName();
        holder.city_name.setText(curr_city);
        holder.city_name.setTag(followed_cities.get(position).getCityId());

        if (curr_city.length() > 15)
        {
            holder.city_name.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 18);
        }
        listView.setOnTouchListener(swipeDetector);

        return itemView;
    }


    public static class ViewHolder
    {
        public TextView city_name;
    }


    @Override

    public int getViewTypeCount()
    {

        return getCount();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position)
    {

        return position;
    }

    private Inflater mInflater;
}
```

Comment: error in this line `mInflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();` , required Java.util.zip.inflater, found android.view.LayoutInflater

Comment: replace it with mInflater = (LayoutInflater)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);